# How to add name attribute to wordpress menu items

Tags: wordpress

http://goo.gl/yB6ST

On this page I list all the galleries on left. I want to add "name" attribute in every link so if you click any item in the menu I can force it to be at the top on a new page. For example, lets say you clicked on "Chicago History Museum" when next page opens "Chicago History Museum" should be at the top, that's what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's just a HTML page, not a wordpress site?
Why can't you just add the name attribute manually then?

    <a name="Chicago History Museum" href="...">Chicago History Museum</a>

Comment: @anuragbh Dude, Its a wordpress site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site is already dead and without its knowledge, the question is not useful any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible with WordPress menu.
First of all I believe that you added the WordPress menu (Not just html menu.)

Go through the following steps.

1. Login to admin dashboard.
2. Goto Appearance -> Menus from left side.
3. Open the menu and add "Title Attribute" next to navigation label.
   [image: WordPress menu]
4. Save your menu. Thats All.

Hope this will helps you. Cheers !!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't do the job that I want. It adds title attribute. Although, I want to add name attribute.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. I thought it was just title attribute. Ok, so why don't you use "menu-id" instead of "name-attribute". Anyway you are handling this with CSS. So use wordpress menu id for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` hook. Try something like this:

```
function my_add_name_attr($link)
{
   // you can get the url and link text. 
   preg_match("/.*?href=\"?'?(.*?)\"?'?>(.*?)</",$link,$m);
   $url=$m[1]; 
   $link_text=$m[2];

   //can be created from the url and link text;
   $name_attribute="my_name_attribute";

    return strstr($link,"href",true)." name=$name_attribute ".strstr($link,"href");
}
add_filter("walker_nav_menu_start_el","my_add_name_attr");
```

See if this would help:

- [wp nav menu: add attributes to menu items](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/103345)
- [Add custom attributes to menu items without plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/100726)

[WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) is a better place for asking WordPress related questions, you will get quicker and better responses.